# How does shell execute piped commands?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to understand that how does shell executes piped commands ? e.g.  cat | more. I am aware that for executing a normal command shell does a fork, execute it and then child returns. But how does shell internally handle the execution of piped commands ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering for example `cat | grep`, the shell first forks itself to start `cat`, and then forks itself once more to start `grep`.

Before calling one of the `exec*` family of functions in the two newly created processes to start the two programs, the tricky part is setting up the pipe and redirecting the descriptors. The `pipe(2)` system call is used in the shell process before forking to return a pair of descriptors which both children inherit - a reading end and a writing end.

The reading end will be closed in the first process (`cat`), and stdout will be redirected to the writing end using the `dup2(2)` system call. Similarly, the writing end in the second process (`grep`) will be closed and stdin will be redirected to the reading end again using `dup2(2)`.

This way both programs are unaware of a pipe because they just work with the standard input/output.

Comment: Hi Blagovest, I am little confused. Is grep a child of cat or a child of shell ? How does cat knows that it has to fork for grep ?

Comment: You are right, bash in particular wouldn't create the second process as a child of the first, but the principle still holds and both processes are still children of the shell.

Answer (score 3):

It sets up a pipe using the [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) system call, forks two processes instead of one and attaches one end of the pipe to the first process' stdout and the other end to the second process' stdin.

Comment: Can you explain how to join stdout of one process with stdin of another ?

Comment: @cppdev: using `dup2`, but you've already found out from Blagovest's answer. @Downvoter: what's wrong with this answer, except that it's too short?

Answer (score 1):

The same, just the stdout of one application is the same as the next stdin. http://unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pipe-fds.html