# How does buffer in bash pipe work on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Think of a simple command as following:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Does `cmd2` start to execute

1. as soon as `cmd1` outputs something
2. or only if `cmd1` completely finishes and exits?

In case 1 when `cmd1` outputs faster than the speed at which `cmd2` consumes, or simply in case 2, there has to be a buffer for the intermediate output.

1. Where is that buffer located? Is it in memory or on disk?
2. Is it possible to configure the buffer's location and size?
3. What would happen when the buffer is not big enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a simple explanation for how pipes work in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834086/608639), [How does shell execute piped commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5101506/608639), [What does a | (pipe character) do in a shell (bash) command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33434465/608639), [Understanding pipe in bash](https://superuser.com/q/178796/173513), etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `cmd2` program starts to run immediately, but whenever it tries to read input, it'll "block" (stop and wait) if necessary until some is available.  This is done automatically by the kernel.  Other than that, the two programs can run concurrently (including at the same time on different CPU cores).

The buffer between the two processes is held by the kernel, and it's in memory (though it might be possible for it to be paged out — I'm not sure).  The *default* size of the buffer doesn't seem to be configurable, but programs can request a bigger size for a specific pipe, and the limit for *that* is configurable by writing to the `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size` file (which, being in `/proc`, isn't a actually a file on disk; it's a virtual file that accesses a setting in the kernel.)  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353728/can-i-increase-the-system-pipe-buffer-max) for more information.

If `cmd1` tries to write but the buffer is full, it will block until some space becomes available in the buffer (which happens when `cmd2` reads some of the buffered data).  So if `cmd1` is producing output too fast, it'll be automatically be slowed down by having to wait for `cmd2` to consume the output.

If the buffer is small, the programs may end up blocking more frequently while waiting on it, which can make them take longer to finish because they'll be spending more time waiting.

In general, there are two categories that most pipelines are likely to fall into:

- `cmd1` produces output faster than `cmd2` consumes it:  the buffer is usually full (or close to it) and `cmd1` often blocks when trying to write, which slows it down to match the speed of `cmd2`.  `cmd2` is able to run at full speed because input is always available in the buffer, so it rarely has to block on reading.
- `cmd2` consumes input faster than `cmd1` produces it: the buffer is usually empty (or close to it), and `cmd2` often blocks when trying to read, which slows it down to match the speed of `cmd1`.  `cmd1` is able to run at full speed because there's always space available for writing to the buffer, so it rarely has to block on writing.

Answer (score 4):

- `cmd1` and `cmd2` run in parallel, both are started immediately
- If `cmd1` is faster, it will block on writes to the pipe. It will not keep writing, and will not require additional buffer space.
- If `cmd2` is faster, it will block on reads to the pipe
- If `cmd1` exits first, the pipe closes and `cmd2` will interpret it as end-of-file and stop
- If `cmd2` exits first, the pipe will close and `cmd1` will receive a SIGPIPE the next time it writes, usually killing it.
- The pipe itself has 4096 bytes guaranteed by POSIX, and (currently) 65536 bytes of in-memory buffer space on Linux. You don't routinely change it. If you need more space, you use temporary files.

Comment: `cmd1` doesn't necessarily exit, though, when it reaches the end of its standard input.